# Odd problem using addObserver:forKeypath:options:context: in init method

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

According to Apple and numerous examples I've seen, there is no problem using KVO/KVC to observer yourself.  Also according to those same sources, it's not a problem setting this up by using addObserver:forKeypath:options:context: in an object's init method, a la:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    [self addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"selected"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Unfortunately for some reason, my observer method does not get called when I do it there.  If I move the addObserver call to another method and then invoke that method in the calling method:

```
MyObject *newObj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[newObj setupObservers];
```

Then all is fine.  This is a subclass of NSImageView, so it's not like there's any 'awakeFromNib'-type alternative here... I'm really scratching my head here and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious - like a rule about things which will cause KVO on self to not work in init methods, but I haven't found anything in the docs which would give me any hints here.

What do I not know?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you should always pass in a unique pointer as the value for context, not NULL. If NSImageView, or some subclass of your class, starts observing self's selected property, everything would go awry if you both used NULL this way.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably that -init is not invoked in your case, -initWithCoder: is.

Every Cocoa class has a set of init methods called its "designated initializers".  Each object, as its being instantiated, is guaranteed to go through one and only one of the designated initializers of each class in its inheritance tree.

If you're subclassing a class and have initialization to do, you must override all of the designated initializers of the superclass.

The designed initializers of NSImageView are -initWithCoder: and initWithFrame:.  Override those two, not init.

Comment: Also, "selected" is too generic of a method to add to a subclass of a NSImageView.  What if Cocoa decided to add a -selected method to NSControl or NSImageView?  The semantics probably wouldn't match yours, and badness would ensue.  See if you can come up with a more specific description of your use than "selected", and if not, use a prefix.

Comment: Somebody find me an idiot stick with which I can hit myself.  How could I miss the fact that init isn't the designated initializer for that class?  Of course that was it and making the appropriate change remedied the problem.  Thanks for reminding me!

And yes, I agree that "selected" is probably not the best property name to use.  I'll come up with something else.  Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

As for the context pointer, the preferred way is:

`static void *MyPrivateObservationContext = (void*)@"MyPrivateObservationContext"; // we assume  MyPrivateObservationContext is a unique name, I use something of the form ClassNamePropertyObservationContext`

then

```
-[obj add....... context:&MyPrivateObservationContext];
```

Then in

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:....context:c;  
{  
    if (c == &MyPrivateObservationContext) {  
        // do work  
    } else {  
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:...];  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there is such restriction or not, but even if you don't have a `awakeFromNib` you can create one by adding `setupObservers` to the run-loop in your init method:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
  performSelector:@selector(setupObservers) 
  target:self 
  argument:nil 
  order:1 
  modes:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Sure, I have little doubt that that would work, but doesn't that seem like a hack?  Also, doing things that way now doesn't really tell me anything about why it wouldn't work in the first place - which means that there's still information that I'm not aware of about what may be poor programming habits on my part.  I'd really rather have things work the way they're supposed to because I'm doing it right...  You know?

Comment: performSelector:afterDelay and its variants are powerful methods that are easily abused. This is an abuse. What happens if selected changes in between now and when the selector eventually fires? What about if we do something that causes us to stop observing - woops haven't started. It's best to avoid using this method to "fix" problems. There are great usages for it, this just isn't one of them.

Comment: @Jon, @Chronor: This is definitely a hack. It just might be a working hack, and sometimes that's good enough... If you can "afford" to call `setupObservers` yourself, then it's obviously better.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a subclass of NSImageView, so
>   it's not like there's any
>   'awakeFromNib'-type alternative
>   here...

I don't understand this point. Are you creating this object in a NIB or not? If a NIB is creating this object, then it will call `-awakeFromNib`. The first thing you should establish (using `NSLog()`) is whether your `-init` is actually running. When nothing happens, it usually means code did not run.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear.  Yes, it is a subclass of NSImageView, but it is one that I am instantiating in code as part of another action.  I then add it as a subview to an existing in-window custom view.  Therefore no awakeFromNib.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to add a KVO notifications to an object that is not yet initialized (your init function add the observer before you return the self). Move the following code:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"selected"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:NULL];
```

into the `- (void)viewDidLoad` instead. It's gonna be fine.

Comment: I was thinking this. But isn't it true that if self = [super init] is called at the top of the init then self is ready to be added as an observer at any point later in the overriding init method?

Comment: Yep but the point is the keyPath instead. The keyPath needs to be initialised before adding the observer. In your case seems like is a BOOL think so the initialisation theory wouldn't work. Try to declare that as _selected into the header and selected into the property with the @synthesize as selected = _selected. That should do the job.